# Python string literal to regex object

Tags: python, regex

I have a function returning a string `"r'^A Plat'"` which is written into a text file

```
get_Pat(file)
    #process text file and now returns "r'^A Plat'"
```

originally, I had it hard coded inside the code.

```
pat = r'^A Plat'
use(pat)
```

now

```
pat = get_Pat(file)
use(pat)
```

But its complaining because i suppose its string instead of regex object.

I have tried

```
re.escape(get_Pat(file))
```

and

```
re.compile(get_Pat(file))
```

but none of them works

How do i convert string literal into regex object?

Is r'^A Plat' a equivalent of simply re.compile("A Plat")?? dumb question, maybe

it would work if its `use("^A Plat'")`
Doesnt work if its `use("r'^A Plat'")`      <--- what get_Pat(file) is spitting out

I suppose my task is simply tranforming string r'^A Plat' in to ^A Plat.
But i feel like its just a cheap hack.

Comment: @aelon See my edit please. I think it gives the solution

Comment: "Is r'^A Plat' a equivalent of simply re.compile("A Plat")?" No; and they have **nothing to do with each other**. The `r` prefix **does not** stand for "regex" or anything like that. There are multiple misconceptions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

```
from ast import literal_eval
pat = literal_eval(get_Pat(file))
```

.

#### EDIT

aelon,

As you wrote in a comment you can't import `literal_eval()`, the above solution of mine is useless for you.
Besides, though expressing interesting information, the other answers didn't brought another solution.
So, I propose a new one, not using `literal_eval()`.

```
import re

detect = re.compile("r(['\"])(.*?)\\1[ \t]*$")

with open('your_file.txt') as f:
    pat = f.readline()

if detect.match(pat):
    r = re.compile(detect.match(pat).group(2))
else:
    r = re.compile(pat)
```

.

## Explanations:

.

Suppose there is the succession of characters `r'^Six o\'clock\nJim'` written as first line of *your_file*

The opening and reading of the first line of *your_file* creates an object **pat**
- its TYPE is `<type 'str'>` in Python 2 and `<class 'str'>` in Python 3
- its REPRESENTATION is `"r'^Six o\'clock\nJim'"`
- its VALUE is `r'^Six o\'clock\nJim'` , that is to say the succession of characters `r` , `'` , `^` , `S` , `i` , `x` ,  , `o` , `\` , `'` , `c` , `l` , `o` , `c` , `k` , `\` , `n` , `J` , `i` , `m`
There may be also the "character" `\n` at the end if there is a second line in the file. And there may be also blanks or tabs, who knows ?, between the end of `r'^Six o\'clock\nJim'` written in the file and the end of its line. That's why I close the regex pattern to define **detect** with `[ \t]*$`.
So, we may obtain possible additional blanks and tabs and newline after the characters of interest, and then if we do `print tuple(pat)` we'll obtain for example:

```
('r', "'", '^', 'S', 'i', 'x', ' ', 'o', '\\', "'", 'c', 'l', 'o', 'c', 'k', '\\', 'n', 'J', 'i', 'm', "'", ' ', ' ', ' ', '\t', '\n')
```

.

Now, let us consider the object obtained with the expression `detect.match(pat).group(2)`.
Its value is `^Six o\'clock\nJim`  , composed of 18 characters, `\` and `'` and `n` being three distinct characters among them, there are not one escaped character `\'` and one escaped character `\n` in it.
This value is exactly the same as the one we would obtain for an object **rawS** of name `rawS`by writing the instruction `rawS = r'^Six o\'clock\nJim'`
Then, we can obtain the regex whose pattern is written in a file under the form `r'....'` by writing directly `r = re.compile(detect.match(pat).group(2))`
In my example, there are only the sequences `\'` and `\n` in the series of characters written in the file. But all that precedes is valid for any of the [Escape Sequences](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)  of the language.

In other words, we don't have to wonder about a function that would do the same as the EXPRESSION `r'^Six o\'clock\nJim'` from the STRING  `"r'^Six o\'clock\nJim'"` of value `r'^Six o\'clock\nJim'` ,
we have directly the result of `r'^Six o\'clock\nJim'` as the value of the string catched by `detect.match(pat).group(2)`.

.

**Nota Bene**

In Python 2, the type `<type 'str'>` is the type of a limited repertoire of characters.
It is the type of the read content of a file, opened as well with mode `'r'` as with mode `'rb'`.

In Python 3, the type `<class 'str'>` covers the unicode characters.
But contrary to Python 3, the read content of a file opened with mode `'r'` is of type `<type 'str'>`
while  it is of type `<class 'bytes'>` if the file is opened with mode `'rb'`.

Then, I think the above code works as well in Python 3 as in Python 2, so such the file is opened with mode `'r'`.

If the file should be opened with `'rb'` the regex pattern should be changed to `b"r(['\"])(.*?)\\1[ \t]*\r?\n"`.

.

AFAIHU

Comment: I think this is exactly what the OP wants.  It would be a better answer if you explained why, though.

Comment: @SethMMorton Maybe you will be interested by the explanation in my edit

Comment: I wish I could +1 again.

Answer (score 2):

`r'^A Plat'` is identical to `'^A Plat'` without the `r`. The `r` stands for **raw**, not regex. It lets you write strings with special characters like `\` without having to escape them.

```
>>> r'^A Plat'
'^A Plat'
>>> r'/ is slash, \ is backslash'
'/ is slash, \\ is backslash'
>>> r'write \t for tab, \n for newline, \" for double quote'
'write \\t for tab, \\n for newline, \\" for double quote'
```

Raw strings are commonly used when writing regexes since regexes often contain backslashes that would otherwise need to be escaped. `r` does **not** create regex objects, though.

From the [Python manual](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> #### § 2.4.1. String literals
>
> String literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter `'r'` or `'R'`; such strings are called *raw strings* and use different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences.
>
> ...
>
> Unless an `'r'` or `'R'` prefix is present, escape sequences in strings are interpreted according to rules similar to those used by Standard C.

Comment: if he had used `re.compile(get_Pat(file))` and it was a raw string returned it would have worked fine, so I don't think that is the problem here.

Comment: ah. i see. so hmm i suppose re doesnt know how to process string which has raw keyword in it and simply treating as a part of the string

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by 'none of them works', but [`re.compile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile) is what you're looking for:

```
>>> def getPat():
...     return r'^A Plat'
...
...
>>> getPat()
'^A Plat'
>>> reObj = re.compile(getPat())
>>> reObj
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x16cfa18>
>>> reObj.match("A Plat")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x16c3058>
>>> reObj.match("foo")
```

**edit:**

You can get rid of the extra `r' '` cruft after it's returned with this code:

```
>>> s = "r'^A Plat'"
>>> s = s[1:].strip("'")
>>> s
'^A Plat'
```

Comment: he wasn't returning r'^A Plat' he was returning "r'^A Plat'" as far as I can understand the comment in the code, as you have pointed out compile works fine with a raw string.

Comment: I guess the question is confusingly written.

Comment: I agree I think it is a bit of an x/y problem with the raw string being a red herring. Could be wrong as its still ambiguous.

Comment: the function is returning "r'A Plat'" not just '^A Plat'

Answer (score 1):

According to the comment in your get_pat function its returning:

> "r'^A Plat'"

Which is not what you thought you were getting:

```
>>> x = re.compile("r'^A Plat'")
>>> y = "A Plat wins"
>>> x.findall(y)
[]
>>> x = re.compile("^A Plat")
>>> x.findall(y)
['A Plat']
>>>
```

So the regex your using isn't r'^A Plat' its "r'^A Plat'", r'^A Plat' is fine:

```
>>> x = re.compile(r'^A Plat')
>>> x.findall(y)
['A Plat']
```

To fix this I would have to understand how you where getting the string "r'^A Plat'" in the first place.

Comment: yes. the problem is that my func is returning string obj of r'^A Plat' so I suppose i could fix it by tranforming that into "^A Plat"

Comment: If you **have** to use the string the function returns you should have a look at eyquems answer

Comment: do not have access to ast import.

Comment: It could help if you posted the code for get_pat() perhaps there is a simple why to fix your problem.

Comment: @Noelkd I've edited my answer with what I think is a valid solution